# So apparently the INDIRECT function doesn't work with data validation in Excel when using a dynamic named range

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-indirect

Trying to create a drop-down list in a cell where the source is a dynamic named range. The named range refers to:

```
=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))
```

Essentially the range starts at A2 and extends down to the last value in the column so that when I add or remove a value I don't end up with blanks in my list or the new values missing. I can use the following as the data validation source for my list with no problem:

```
=Named_Range
```

It provides me with a drop-down list of everything in the named range.

However, when I type the named range's name (Named_Range) into a cell (say F1) and use the following as the data validation source for my list, I don't get the drop-down list:

```
=INDIRECT(F1)
```

Searching around revealed that this is a know issue, but I can't get my head around a workaround.

Comment: Why are you using `=Indirect(F1)` instead of `=Named_Range`?

Comment: Because F1 itself is a data validated drop-down list.
If I select "Named_Range" in F1 then my cell containing =INDIRECT(F1) should return a dropdown list containing the items in "Named_Range".
But I could select "Named_Range2" in F1 and then =INDIRECT(F1) should then return a different drop-down list.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating dynamic lists using the method you are using, I suggest using `Tables`.

Create a table for each dependent drop-down list.
  - Be sure to select "my table has headers"

Then

- Select the data area of each Table (not the header)
- In the `Name` box to the left of the formula bar, type in the appropriate Name
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the name for the databodyrange.
- Repeat for each table.

Since this is a table, the lists will autoadjust as you add/delete rows
You can refer to them with the `INDIRECT` function as you set up your data validation list formula.

Comment: I tried creating Tables but that didn't work for me either. Is there another simple work around instead of using offset?

Comment: @techscolasticus You haven't supplied enough information for me to even hazard a guess. I suggest you post a new question with the specifics of your problem, what you have tried, and your desired results. If you haven't has yet, take a look at the the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will help the respondents to help you best with your problem.